# What is the best way to search a List<List<string>>?

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

Say I have the following list:

```
List 1:
{{"John", "Doe", "Tall", "Old"},
{"John", "Doe", "Short", "Old"},
{"Jane", "Doe", "Tall", "Young"},
{"Jane", "Doe", "Short", "Old"}}
```

And I want to search the list for {"John", "Doe", "Short", "Old"}.

What is the best way to search for this nested list entry and ensure I don't get {"John", "Doe", "Tall", "Old"} instead?

If the nested list contained only one `string` item instead of four, I would use LINQ to flatten the list and search the resulting `List<string>.` i.e.:

```
List<string> newList = oldList.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
newList.Contains("string");
```

Is there something similar I can do for a list that contains more than one string item per each nested list?

Comment: This is either a convoluted example, or you're in object denial. That is you should have an object to represent FirstName,LastName,Height and Age.

Comment: Seems a strange format for your data. However, if that's how you want to store it, why flatten it to perform the search? You can search as is without creating lots of transient objects.

Comment: @user2586804 This is to be used for testing purposes and nothing too fancy, so I'm trying to keep it basic using the string object. I am hoping to reuse the function to compare multiple nested lists whose nested lists may have 4 objects, or they may have 84. Using specified objects for my current purposes would be overkill, I would think.

Comment: @TestK An object takes seconds to define, it probably took more effort to write this question. And forget re-usability for now and solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the list must contain all strings in that order? Then you can use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`. If the order is not important use `Enumerable.All` with `Contains`, so:

```
var names = new[]{"John", "Doe", "Short", "Old"};
List<List<string>> result = list
    .Where(l => l.SequenceEqual(names)).ToList();
```

or

```
result = list
    .Where(l => l.All(name => names.Contains(name))).ToList();
```

Output:

```
foreach(List<string> l  in result)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", l));  // John,Doe,Short,Old
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Mdr61h)</kbd>

Side-note: you could make the second approach  more efficient if you convert the collection  you are searching to a `HashSet<T>`:

```
var names = new HashSet<string>(new[]{"John", "Doe", "Short", "Old"});
result = list.Where(l => l.All(names.Contains)).ToList();
```

As Servy has mentioned, the second approach does not prevent you from getting lists that contain all the items but also  more. You could add a `Count` check to ensure it.

Comment: Note that the all/contains will match a list that has items not in the sequence you're searching with; you need to do something more involved to account for that.

Comment: @Servy: Good point, edited my answer to mention it. I think a simple `Count` comparison would be sufficient.

Comment: Regardless it's generally complicated enough that I'd suggest creating a "SetEquals" method to hold all of the logic, thus also allowing you to change/fix the implementation.  Another alternative is to use `HashSet.CreateSetComparer` to handle it for you.  That's my personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use overloaded version of [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which allows to pass custom equality comparer (`IEqualityComparer<T>`).

Answer (score 2):

One way of "flattening" the list would be as follows:

```
var people = list1.
    Select(lst => new {
        First  = lst[0]
    ,   Last   = lst[1]
    ,   Height = lst[2]
    ,   Age    = lst[3]
    });
```

Now you can search for containment as follows:

```
bool hasShortOldJohnDoe = people
    .Contains(p => p.First=="John"
                && p.Last=="Doe"
                && p.Height == "Short"
                && p.Age=="Old");
```

Comment: Anonymous types implement equality, so you could simplify this further by searching for a `var myPerson = new { First = "John", ... };`. You could even do so inside a `HashSet` if that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
List<List<string>> mainList = new List<List<string>>

{
    new List<string>(){"John", "Doe", "Tall", "Old"},
    new List<string>(){"John", "Doe", "Short", "Old"},
    new List<string>(){"Jane", "Doe", "Tall", "Young"},
    new List<string>(){"Jane", "Doe", "Short", "Old"},
};
List<string> searchList = new List<string>() { "John", "Doe", "Short", "Old" };

var temp = mainList[0].Except(searchList).Count();
List<List<string>> result  = mainList
                                .Where(r => r.Except(searchList).Count() == 0)
                                .ToList();
```

It will give you one item in the `result`.

Or:

```
var  result = mainList
                  .Where(r => !r.Except(searchList).Any());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of ways:

```
 [Test]
    public void Using_String_Join()
    {
        var l = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string> {"John", "Doe", "Tall", "Old"},
            new List<string> {"John", "Doe", "Short", "Old"},
            new List<string> {"Jane", "Doe", "Tall", "Young"},
            new List<string> {"Jane", "Doe", "Short", "Old"}
        };

        var l2 = new List<string> {"John", "Doe", "Short", "Old"};

        Assert.That(l.Count(inner => string.Join(",", inner).Equals(string.Join(",", l2))), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Using_SequenceEqual()
    {
        var l = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string> {"John", "Doe", "Tall", "Old"},
            new List<string> {"John", "Doe", "Short", "Old"},
            new List<string> {"Jane", "Doe", "Tall", "Young"},
            new List<string> {"Jane", "Doe", "Short", "Old"}
        };

        var l2 = new List<string> {"John", "Doe", "Short", "Old"};

        Assert.That(l.Count(inner => inner.SequenceEqual(l2)), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }
```